# how can I make while loop wait for a future .:WITHOUT:. making the function async?

Tags: asynchronous, while-loop, dart, flutter, async-await

aye aye goof people,

Given that I'm working inside an Isolate so, that I'm aware of,

I cannot make the function async:

I need to run a while loop until gets a result, but as it is

doesn't wait for the future to be returned so it's flooding my stream :(

the following code is fictional (for everyone convenience)

but gives the idea:

```
Future<String> futureString() async {
    String myString;
    mySink.add(0);
    await for (String _string in myStream) => myString =_string;
    return myString;
}

///### the following fun one cannot be async!!! ###

static String myFunction()  {
    String myString
    while (myString==null) {
      myString=futureString();
    }      
    return myString;
  }
}
```

Any idea?

thanks in advance for the help

Francesco

Comment: You can use async/await with isolates

Comment: @RémiRousselet apparently  I can use  them, but not always is not always, for example 'bi-directionally '